# Why does the EXCEPT clause trim whitespace at the end of text?

Tags: sql-server

I read through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the SqlServer EXCEPT operator and I see no mention of explicit trimming of white space at the end of a string.  However, when running:

```
SELECT 'Test'
EXCEPT
SELECT 'Test '
```

no results are returned.  Can anyone explain this behavior or how to avoid it when using EXCEPT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSI SQL-92 requires strings to be the same length before comparing and the pad character is a space.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces for more information

In the ANSI standard (accessed [here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) section 8.2 )

> 3) The comparison of two character strings is determined as follows:
>
> ```
>         a) If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length
>           in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively
>           replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of
>           itself that has been extended to the length of the longer
>           string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad char-
>           acters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS. If
>           CS has the NO PAD attribute, then the pad character is an
>           implementation-dependent character different from any char-
>           acter in the character set of X and Y that collates less
>           than any string under CS. Otherwise, the pad character is a
>           <space>.
>
>         b) The result of the comparison of X and Y is given by the col-
>           lating sequence CS.
>
>         c) Depending on the collating sequence, two strings may com-
>           pare as equal even if they are of different lengths or con-
>           tain different sequences of characters. When the operations
>           MAX, MIN, DISTINCT, references to a grouping column, and the
>           UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT operators refer to character
>           strings, the specific value selected by these operations from
>           a set of such equal values is implementation-dependent.
> ```

If this behaviour must be avoided, you can reverse the columns as part of your EXCEPT:

```
SELECT 'TEST', REVERSE('TEST')
EXCEPT
SELECT 'TEST ', REVERSE('TEST ')
```

which gives the expected result, though is quite annoying especially if you're dealing with multiple columns.

The alternative would be to find a collating sequence with an alternate pad character or a no pad option set, though this seems to not exist in t-sql after a quick google.

Alternatively, you could terminate each column with a character and then substring it out in the end:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col,1,LEN(col) -1) FROM 
(
    SELECT 'TEST' + '^' as col
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT 'TEST ' + '^'
) results
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.  Is there any way to avoid the behavior?

Comment: I believe that would be up to the collating sequence, though I can't find any that use an alternate pad character in t-sql or that have the `NO PAD` option set. Not sure if that's a version thing (I only have 2008 available to me at the moment) or a t-sql thing. Answer edited with a hacky workaround